# How to do Try-Finally in ReScript?

Tags: exception, dry, rescript

According to ReScript's [documentation](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/overview#exception), try-catch blocks cannot have a `finally` clause.

My question is twofold:

Firstly, what on Earth possessed them? What was the motivation? How does removing this functionality help us as developers? After all, the entire point of building yet another wrapper around JS is to provide a better experience, yes?

And secondly, what do they expect us to use instead? Sure, if we're writing the function that throws, we can eschew exceptions entirely and return an `option`; but if we're calling a JS function (or an RS function written by someone else) we don't have that...well...*option*.

Short of duplicating the cleanup code in *all possible code paths*, I have to admit I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

ReScript is not a language built on top of JavaScript. It's a language built on top of OCaml and compiles to JavaScript.

The reason it does not exist in OCaml is probably because it was deemed unnecessary initially, given a minimalist approach, and exceptions later deemed non-idiomatic with the existence of `option` and `result`.

It can easily be user-defined as a simple function:

```js
let protect = (~finally, f) => {
  let result = try f() catch {
  | exn =>
    finally()
    raise(exn)
  }
  finally()
  result
}
```

Comment: Proposed addition to `rescript-core`: https://github.com/rescript-association/rescript-core/pull/155

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "built on top of ocaml". The language syntax presumably differs from that of ocaml, and therefore requires a parser, and thus supporting `finally` is completely possible. Exceptions will be thrown at runtime from Java, not from OCaml. Whatever language the _parser_ was written in is immaterial.

Comment: A language is much more than just a parser. The syntax is almost irrelevant, it's the semantics that matter, and the semantics come from OCaml. It just happens to line up with JavaScript in most places, which makes it easy to write a back-end that compiles to nice readable JavaScript.

Comment: Adding syntax sugar for `finally` is definitely possible, but probably not worth the complexity. I've followed the language since its creation, as well as its precursors (ReasonML, BuckleScript), and not once have I seen anyone ask for this. Or needed it myself. I can certainly understand the frustration when you do need it, but the workaround is pretty simple and easy. Therefore, if I were a language developer and had to decide whether to work on this or something else, I'd probably choose something else. There's no shortage of feature requests that would add much more value than this.